# Release an application on iPhone React-Native

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is it possible to install an app on an iPhone without publish it on the Apple Store ? I've already make an archive but all the options are greyed. I have a free developer account, maybe that's why ? I just want to install the app on multiple devices just to test it before publish it on the store.

Thanks !

Comment: Please approve the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to 'test' a `iOS` app without a payed Apple Developer account. For a complete tutorial on how to go about this, click [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861).

If you publish your app to Expo you'll be able to run it anytime, anywere. If it works on Expo the chance of it not working on a real publish to the App Store is really small.